# CSS: scroll bar in inner div of fixed parent

Tags: css

Here is the link to [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/hufen/2/edit)

`modules` is fixed container with 100% height. I'm trying get the list items to scroll keeping the `search` div fixed in the `wrapper` container so that search is always visible. Trying to do this with CSS only.

```
  <div class="modules">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="search">
        <input type="text" placeholder="search" />
      </div>
      <div class="items-container">
        <ul>
          <li>Stuff First</li>
          <li>Stuff Last</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


.modules {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 90px;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 240px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
}

.search{
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.25);
  padding: 5px;
}

.items-container{
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add something like this:

```
#items-container ul { 
    height: 195px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    width: 100%; 
}
```

See: http://jsbin.com/tucakikutica/2/edit

Answer (score 0):

There is a spelling mistake in assigning css class "items-container"...
In the mean time give some specific height to item container

```
   .items-container{
      overflow: auto;  
      height:400px;
    }
```

Comment: Items-container height should be adjusted to parent which is dynamic to window height

Answer (score 0):

You have to apply `position:fixed` to input search:

```
.search{
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.25);
  padding: 5px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/busfsf2h/7/)

Another version:

**css**

```
.modules {
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0px;
  z-index: 15;
  width: 240px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  /*overflow: scroll;*/
}

.search{
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.25);
  padding: 5px;
  position: fixed;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 100;
}

.items-container{
  padding-top: 40px;
}

ul{
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li{
  padding: 3px 5px;
}
li:hover{
  background: #f6f6f6;
}
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/busfsf2h/16/)

Also you have a typo `<div clas="items-container">`. Is `class` not `clas`.